# How is an 'undefined symbol' error possible if shared dependencies provide that symbol?

Tags: c++, linux, linker, gtk, wayland

I'm trying to compile GTK 3.24.33 from source. At some point in the build process I got the following error

```
Cannot load module /home/felix/apps/src/libraries/gtk-3.24.33/modules/input/im-wayland.la: /home/felix/apps/src/libraries/gtk-3.24.33/modules/input/.libs/im-wayland.so: undefined symbol: wl_proxy_marshal_flags
```

Indeed

```
nm /home/felix/apps/src/libraries/gtk-3.24.33/modules/input/.libs/im-wayland.so | grep wl_proxy_marshal_flags
```

returns

```
U wl_proxy_marshal_flags
```

If I do

```
ldd /home/felix/apps/src/libraries/gtk-3.24.33/modules/input/.libs/im-wayland.so
```

I get among other dependencies

```
libwayland-client.so.0 => /home/felix/apps/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-client.so.0 (0x00007f417c745000)
```

and

```
nm /home/felix/apps/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-client.so.0 | grep wl_proxy_marshal_flags
```

returns

```
0000000000006740 T wl_proxy_marshal_flags
```

How is it possible that there occurs an `undefined symbol` error? It seems to me as if there's all the necessary information available to find the symbol `wl_proxy_marshal_flags`.

Comment: Is it expecting a "C" symbol or a "C++" symbol?  You had to demangle it to show it.

Comment: @stark It is expecting "C" symbols. I just checked again without using `--demangle`. Thank you for the comment. I'll edit my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

> How is it possible that there occurs an undefined symbol error? It seems to me as if there's all the necessary information available to find the symbol wl_proxy_marshal_flags.

There are at least two possible answers:

1. The symbol definition is *present* in `libwayland-client.so.0`, but is not exported from it.
2. Some other version of `libwayland-client.so.0` is getting loaded into whatever binary is invoked in the failing build step.

To prove or disprove (1), use `nm -D /home/felix/apps/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-client.so.0 | grep wl_proxy_marshal_flags`. If the symbol appears in `nm -D ...` output, then it is *is* exported (and available for linking by `im-wayland.so`). If it doesn't, then (1) is the root cause.

To figure out which `libwayland-client.so.0` is getting loaded during the build, you'll have to figure out which `Makefile` command is being executed, and prefix it with `env LD_DEBUG=files,libs ...`. Using that environment variable instructs the dynamic loader to print which binaries and libraries it is loading. Search that output for `libwayland-client.so.0`. If the system version (instead of the one you built) is getting loaded, that version may not have `wl_proxy_marshal_flags` exported from it.

If (2) is the cause, you may have to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before executing the build. (This would also imply that the `Makefile`s for GTK are broken.)

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution for people dropped off by google with amdgpu, maybe after updating some ubuntu 22.04:

> In my case the problem was that the referred libwayland showing in ldd
> (e.g. ldd -r krusader - or whenever executable that gives you the
> issue) is in /opt/admgpu instead the one in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu.

> Do not know exactly the reason for that. After upgrade this led to several problems (for example cannot get libgtk3 working again unless
> downgrading it).

> Finally, the solution for me was to edit amdgpu files
> in /etc/ld.so.conf.d by adding /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu at the first
> line. Then, rebuild the ld indexes with `sudo rm /etc/ld.so.cache` and
> `sudo ldconfig`. This way the ldd resolves the correct linked objects
> and things get to work again.

My `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/20-amdgpu.conf` looks like

```
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```